# How to access a private github image file with an access_token and render to html

Tags: reactjs, github, octokit-js

I have an application where a user logs in via oauth, i have access to the user's github `access_token`.

I want to be able to render a private repository image to html, using the users access_token `or something i can obtain via the access_token?`

for exmaple

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MyORG/my-private-repo/master/architecture.drawio.png?token=<UNKNOWN_TOKEN>
```

**react render componetn**

```
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MyORG/my-private-repo/master/architecture.drawio.png?token=<UNKNOWN_TOKEN>" alt="image-service">
```

I have tried using the `access_token` in place of this `UNKNOWN_TOKEN` but it does not work.

I am able to curl the image, but i need the image to be rendered via a html tag at run time.

```
curl  -X GET -H "Authorization: token <ACCESS_TOKEN>" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MyORG/iy-private-repo/master/architecture.drawio.png --output some.pnpg
```

I am attemtping to render README.md to a custom react/nextjs web page. However their are image links within the README.md which are not rendered because they require auth.

I get the initial README.md via https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28

[image]